# Integrate junction and lookup tables with a basic Access database

Tags: forms, ms-access-2007, lookup-tables, junction-table

I have a simple database that stores a customer's name, city and state.   I've added to this two new tables.  One is a lookup table, for describing a car model, and the second is a junction table for setting up one or more car models with a customer record.

Here's the relationship layout as of now:

[image]

And datasheets for each table.  `cust_id` and `model_id` are auto increment columns.

**demographics**

[image]

**lookup_model**

[image]

**junction_model**

[image]

Using a scripting language, MySQL and HTML I could whip up a complete form in a few minutes.  I am having a little trouble figuring out how this is done in Access 2007.

Two features I need are

1. Ability to edit/add items to the lookup table
2. Ability to add new customer records including selecting from cars found in the lookup table, while maintaining primary key relationships.

Ex:

> "Mary Jane" owns a Ford Pinto and Datson 510.  When I add her info
>   with the to-be-created form, her cust_id would be 5, and two new
>   entries would show up in the junction table with her cust_id:  2
>   (ford) and 5 (datsun).

Is there a relatively painless way of setting up this form in Access 2007?

Edit: this is what I've managed to get working so far.  This subform lists the correct model/cust associations, but I am looking to show a combo box with only the model_desc shown (not the model id).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form containing a "subform" will serve you well in a case like this.

- You can create a form named "Owners" that is bound to the [demographics] table in which you can add/edit the owner information (name, address, ...).
- You can create a "continuous forms" form named something like "Cars_Owned_subform" that is bound to the [junction_model] table. That form will contain a combo box whose Row Source is the [lookup_model] table, displaying the [model_desc] and returning the [model_id].
- Then you can add a Subform control to the "Owners" table using the Subform Wizard and it will help you link up the Subform to its parent based on [cust_id]. Then as you move from one Owner to the next their cars will automatically update in the subform, and if you add a new car in the subform it will automatically be associated with the [cust_id] of the Owner whose record is currently being displayed.

As for editing the lookup table, you could very easily create a simple form to edit the [lookup_model] table.

### Edit re: question update

To have a combo box that *displays* the [model_desc] and *returns* the [model_id] you'll want to have the combo box "display" two columns where the first column has a width of zero. That is, the Format properties of the combo box should include values like...

Column Count: 2
Column Widths: 0";1.3646"

...and the Data properties should include values like...

Row Source: lookup_model
Bound Column: 1

The final result would look something like this:

[image: owners_form.png]

The subform in Design View would simply be:

[image: subform.png]

Comment: I think the combo box is working now.  But it only shows one selected item.  I have to use a datasheet view to show all contents from junction_models, but here I am only seeing the IDs.  Is there a better way to show data that is already selected, in a human readable form?

Comment: @acoder RE: showing multiple items - On the Format tab of the Property sheet for the [cars_owned_subform], make sure that the Default View is set to "Continuous Forms". (p.s. I added some screenshots to my answer.)

Comment: 1) Can I disallow multiples of the same value?  2) Can I let users delete an existing customer-car association?

Comment: Since your answer successfully addresses this question, I've created another dealing with #2 above:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531496/delete-row-from-access-junction-table-via-form

Comment: @acoder RE: Can I disallow multiples of the same value? - Your Primary Key on [junction_model] is ([cust_id], [model_id]) so each person will only be able to "own" the same model once.