# Delete row from Access junction table via form

Tags: ms-access-2007, delete-row, junction-table

I set up a subform [listing stored values from a junction and lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16528529).   This part is working nicely (I can view all stored entries or add new ones).

Here are my relationships:

[image]

And here's the layout of my form showing where I attempted to remove a previously saved association.   If I simply delete the contents of the row in the form, Access returns this when I try to save the record: `index or primary key cannot contain null value`

[image]

The SQL to remove a row from a console is straightforward:

```
DELETE FROM junction_model WHERE cust_id = X AND model_id = Y
```

Removing a row from the form is proving not to be as straightforward.

Is there a relatively easy way of doing this from the form itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those little squares to the left of the combo boxes (one of which has a "pencil" icon in it, indicating a dirty record) are the "record selectors". Clicking a record selector will select the record, then if you hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> the record will be deleted.

It looks like you just deleted the *contents* of the combo box. When you went to save the (still-existing) record Access objected because the `.Value` of the combo box was `Null`, and your Primary Key on the junction table prohibits `Null` values for [model_id].

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others combing back to this:

One option (perhaps more intuitive for the user) is to add a Delete button to your subform. Open the subform in Design view and add a Button from the Controls palette, with control wizard turned on. Command Button Wizard should open - choose 'Record Operations' from the Categories list and 'Delete Record' from the Actions list. The rest of the wizard will customize the look and name of the button.

I'm using a similar form and each row looks like this, with the (X) being a little delete button after the combo box:

---

**Ford Pinto**    (X)

---

If deleting is important, I think the button is a much more visible method than clicking the 'record selector' and pressing the delete key.

Comment: THanks - will be working on this DB again soon and will see how this plays out.